# How can I install debugbar in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, xdebug

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare measure() (previously declared in C:\wamp64\www\acellemailll\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-debugbar\src\helpers.php:77) in C:\wamp64\www\acellemailll\app\Helpers\helpers.php on line 427

Comment: Please describe why installing "debugbar" will resolve your issue? Accordingly to the error message you have it installed already. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: After i install the debugbar it shows that message and the project doesn't run anymore; what i meant is how can i install it without this error

Comment: The error is in YOUR code (`...\acellemailll\app\Helpers\helpers.php` file). You are **re-declaring** the global function named `measure()` that is **already defined** by Laravel Debugbar package. You cannot do that -- it's basic PHP knowledge. Give your function another name... or get rid of Laravel Debugbar package so it does not introduce that function in first place.

Comment: i changed the function name in my code and it still doesn't show the bar of debug

Comment: *"...it still doesn't show the bar of debug"* -- so it must be some another issue. E.g. did you added that package ServiceProvider into appropriate place? Auto-discovery is available since Laravel 5.5; before that they should be added manually. Follow the instructions.

Answer (score 12):

Open the terminal and to do like this as your wise

1) Install DebugBar

- The DebugBar 2.4.x is for **Laravel 5.4-**
- The DebugBar 3.0.x is for **Laravel 5.5+**

A) Install the debuger 2.4 ([Documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/2.4))

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:~2.4
```

You will also need to add in `providers` array in `config/app.php` :

```
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class
```

B) Install the debuger 3.0 ([Documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar))

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev
```

2) After that, you need to update the composer

```
composer update
```

3) Clear cache and config

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache
```

4) Then after you need to add a line to `.env` file

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to your project folder and paste in the following

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev`

Answer (score 1):

composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

open config/app.php and inside the ‘providers’ array add:

'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-debugbar